# How to use NeedsRestart parameter of PrepareToTinstall function in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

In `AllPagesExample.iss` example file there's this part:

```pascal
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
  if SuppressibleMsgBox('Do you want to stop Setup at the Preparing To Install wizard page?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO, IDNO) = IDYES then
    Result := 'Stopped by user';
end;
```

If `PrepareToTinstall` is an event function and I don't call it myself, how can I pass `NeedsRestart` parameter to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NeedsRestart` parameter is [passed by a reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference) (the `var` keyword). So its value is returned from the function similarly to the return value of the function itself (`Result`).

As the [documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PrepareToInstall) says:

> Return a non empty string to instruct Setup to stop at the [Preparing to Install](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=wizardpages) wizard page, showing the returned string as the error message. Set `NeedsRestart` to True (and return a non empty string) if a restart is needed. If Setup is stopped this way, it will exit with a dedicated exit code as described in [Setup Exit Codes](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupexitcodes).

So, what you want to do, is to assign a value to the parameter and Inno Setup will act accordingly once the event function exits.

```pascal
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
  Result := '';
  if DoWeNeedRestartBeforeInstalling then
  begin
    Result := 'You need to restart your machine before installing';
    NeedsRestart := True;
  end;
end;
```

[image]